# Mobile devices: which kind of user's "mobile device behaviours" could be tracked by a third party app?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, mobile

I would like to know - for different mobile os (iOS, Android, Windows Phone) - what informations could retrieve an app installed on the device regarding the actions that the user has done using its device. For example:

An app could be able to see the list of running apps on the device? I think the answer is true for Android and not true for iOS. But I'm not sure.

or

An app could be able to see the browning history of the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the available permissions that Android applications can request.

You can see the list of permissions here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

In Android, you are able to get the list of running applications. Check out the GET_TASKS permission: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_TASKS